# Bucles anidados en R

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo 3 dataframe que contienen la siguiente información:

df1

```
COD      LON       LAT       ALT
C037    -289.976   432.165   162
E000    -274.107   430.783   218
C068    -228.623   428.395   596
```

df2 #Tantos datos por COD como fechas (que están contenidas en el df3)

```
 C037    C038    G0E7    G0E9    G0EA    G0F0    G0F4    G0E5    G0B6    G0C1    
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999    
1.456   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
```

df3 #Fechas desde el 01/01/2000 hasta el 31/12/2015 (5844 registro)

```
Date
01/01/2000
02/01/2000
03/01/2000
04/01/2000
05/01/2000
06/01/2000
07/01/2000
08/01/2000
09/01/2000
10/01/2000
11/01/2000
12/01/2000
13/01/2000
14/01/2000
```

Tengo que hacer un bucle para crear una matriz final que contenga

```
FECHA        COD   ALT        LAT        LON  datosdf2
01/01/2000   C037  -289.976   432.165    162   -9999
02/01/2000   C037  -289.976   432.165    162   1.456
```

Así sucesivamente rellenar los registros del df2 para cada día hasta el 31/12/2015.

```
01/01/2000   E000   -274.107   430.783   218   -9999
```

Hacer lo mismo para 200 códigos más

Estoy intentando algo así, pero sinceramente no sé si está bien o no, nunca he hecho este tipo de cosas en R

Creo que tengo que hacer algo del tipo:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) 
  for (j in 1:ncol(df2)){
   if (df1(i,1)==(df2(1,j)){ #Esto es, si el COD del df1 coincide con el COD del df 2 (que estaría en la fila 1, columna 1), entonces que tome los valores registrados en el df2
   print ("i is 1", "1 is j")
```

En este punto no sé cómo indicarle que tome los registros de las fechas y los añada a la matriz... Tampoco sé cómo hacer para indicarle al programa que cuando tenga que tomar el siguiente COD, me añanda nuevamente las fechas desde 01/01/2000 sin machacarme las que ya tiene registradas antes.

Espero que entiendan lo que quiero decir y lo que debo conseguir al final. Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Hola Carolina, bienvenida. ¿Necesitas forzosamente hacerlo con un bucle por algún otro motivo? Si en cada data.frame tienes una columna con un código que está presente en los demás, una alternativa mucho mejor sería hacer una operación que se llama join. La función base `merge`, debería ser muy fácil de escribir y no tendrías que reinventar la rueda... De nuevo, bienvenida.

Comment: Si, tengo que usar un bucle con sentencias condicionales pero estoy super perdida.  if (df1(i,1)==(df2(1,j)) Este paso no me sale, me da error...

Answer (score 1):

Hola el siguiente código te puede ayudar, se utiliza el `tidyverse` en lugar de bucles

```
library(tidyverse)

dt1<-tribble(
   ~COD ,     ~LON,       ~LAT,       ~ALT,
   "C037",    -289.976,   432.165,   162,
   "E000",    -274.107,   430.783,  218,
   "C038",    -228.623,   428.395,   596#Agregue C038
 )

 dt2<-tribble(#una parte de tu ejemplo
   ~C037,    ~C038,     
   -9999,   -9999,       
   1.456,   -9999,   
   -9999,   -9999,   
   -9999,   -9999 
 )

 dt3<-tribble(
   ~Date,
   "01/01/2000",
   "02/01/2000",
   "03/01/2000",
  "04/01/2000"
 )

 #Primero si hay tantas fechas como datos en dt2, los combinamos

 dt4<-cbind(dt3,dt2)
 dt4
        Date      C037  C038
1 01/01/2000 -9999.000 -9999
2 02/01/2000     1.456 -9999
3 03/01/2000 -9999.000 -9999
4 04/01/2000 -9999.000 -9999

 n<-ncol(dt4)#Numero de columnas en dt4
 #Pasamos los nombres de las columnas a una nueva variable "COD"
 #Las observaciones de cada COD por fecha se pasan a la variable "VALUE"
 dt4<-gather(dt4, "COD", "VALUE", 2:n)
 dt4
        Date  COD     VALUE
1 01/01/2000 C037 -9999.000
2 02/01/2000 C037     1.456
3 03/01/2000 C037 -9999.000
4 04/01/2000 C037 -9999.000
5 01/01/2000 C038 -9999.000
6 02/01/2000 C038 -9999.000
7 03/01/2000 C038 -9999.000
8 04/01/2000 C038 -9999.000

 #Agregamos dagtos de lat, lon, alt por cordenada
 #La siguiente funcion agrega los datos sólo a las cordenadas presentes en dt4
 dt5<-left_join(dt4,dt1,"COD")
 dt5
        Date  COD     VALUE      LON     LAT ALT
1 01/01/2000 C037 -9999.000 -289.976 432.165 162
2 02/01/2000 C037     1.456 -289.976 432.165 162
3 03/01/2000 C037 -9999.000 -289.976 432.165 162
4 04/01/2000 C037 -9999.000 -289.976 432.165 162
5 01/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596
6 02/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596
7 03/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596
8 04/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596

 #Se puede usar full join para unir todos los datos pero quedarian sin fecha 
 full_join(dt4,dt1,"COD")
        Date  COD     VALUE      LON     LAT ALT
1 01/01/2000 C037 -9999.000 -289.976 432.165 162
2 02/01/2000 C037     1.456 -289.976 432.165 162
3 03/01/2000 C037 -9999.000 -289.976 432.165 162
4 04/01/2000 C037 -9999.000 -289.976 432.165 162
5 01/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596
6 02/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596
7 03/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596
8 04/01/2000 C038 -9999.000 -228.623 428.395 596
9       <NA E000        NA -274.107 430.783 218
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te **obligan** que lo hagas con bucles y condicionales es posible. Coincido que un join es la mejor opción, pero se puede hacer con estructuras de control explícitas.

## Los datos

> Sería muy importante que confirmes que tus datos tienen la estructura que los que se están usando de ejemplo y test en este hilo. Por "la misma estructura" me refiero a que tienen las mismas filas y columnas con el mismo tipo de datos en cada una. Caso contrario el código no va a funcionar.

Retomo los datos que creó Rolando, aunque le cambio los nombres.

```
    library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
   ~COD ,     ~LON,       ~LAT,       ~ALT,
   "C037",    -289.976,   432.165,   162,
   "E000",    -274.107,   430.783,  218,
   "C038",    -228.623,   428.395,   596#Agregue C038
 )

 df2 <- tribble(#una parte de tu ejemplo
   ~C037,    ~C038,     
   -9999,   -9999,       
   1.456,   -9999,   
   -9999,   -9999,   
   -9999,   -9999 
 )

 df3 <- tribble(
   ~Date,
   "01/01/2000",
   "02/01/2000",
   "03/01/2000",
  "04/01/2000"
 )
```

## El bucle con el que lo estabas intentando

La insistencia en que un join es mejor que un bucle va a estar clara acá: uno de los problemas de los bucles es que tenés "decir" explícitamete qué hacer en cada paso y luego dónde y cómo ir guardando el resultado. Por eso corresponden a un paradigma de programación *imperativo*. El join sería una operación del paradigma *declarativo*, le indicas a tu función cuál es el resultado que buscas y la funcion se enarga del trabajo engorroso.

Ahora bien, ¿por qué **no** funciona tu bucle?

1. Tiene problemas de sintaxis. Le faltan algunos símbolos para ordenar el código y el intérprete semántico (parser) de R se pierde y no sabe que hacer. La sintaxis básica de un bucle `for` es:

`for (indice in iterador) {hacer_algo_con_índice}`

Dada esta sintaxis a tu código le faltan una llave `{` abriendo dentro del primer bucle y dos llaves `}` cerrando al final. Eso sin contar las llaves del `if`.

2. El subset o creación de subconjuntos de datos en R se hace -entre otras maneras, pero esta es la más usual-  con los símbolos `[ ]`, corchetes. En la línea tres de tu código estás usando paréntesis `( )`. Al usar paréntesis le estás diciento a R que lo que está detrás es una función, no una estructura de datos. Entonces R intenta ejecutar la función `df1` con los argumentos `(i, 1)`. Obviamente falla, porque no existe tal función.
3. El output. Usando un bucle `for` es necesario explicitar a dónde se va a guardando lo que quieres que te devuelva al final. En términos más técnicos: ir asignando el valor de salida en una nueva estructura de datos.
   En tu código no hay nada de esto, por lo tanto aún si funcionara a la perfección no te regresaría nada al final. Haría el procesamiento, pero el resultado se perdería. Veo que incluyes un `print` "al final" de tu bucle. Puede ser que eso sea lo que quieres, que el bucle sólo regrese **en pantalla** el resultado. Es estaría bien para un usuario humano que está leyendo la pantalla, pero no te crearía unos datos de output que pudieras seguir usando después de procesar el bucle. En términos técnicos produce un efecto colateral (side effect), pero no un output propiamente dicho.

> En la solución de más abajo eso es lo que hacen los `cbind()` y `rbind()` de `x`, `y`, `z` y `out`, ir armando paso a paso el output final.

4. El `print` de la línea 4 no va a regresar nada. Aún si funcionara agregando la función `paste` para que concatene las cadenas de caracteres entrecomilladas te regresaría siempre una constante: `"i is 11 is j"`. No tiene mucho caso hacer un bucle para que regrese siempre lo mismo :). Además, como vimos en punto anterior, lo que te interesa es obtener una estructura de datos al final, no la impresión en pantalla. Así que print no se usa, excepto quizás para hacer debuggin del código o como ayuda mientras lo estás construyendo.

   ```
   for (i in 1:nrow(df1))          #Falta una llave abriendo, si no R no sabe cuando comienza el bucle
     for (j in 1:ncol(df2)){       #Es está "bien"
      if (df1(i,1)==(df2(1,j)){    #En df1(i, 1) debería ser df1[i,1]
      print ("i is 1", "1 is j")   #Acá no hay output, de hecho no hay nada.
   ```

## ¿Cómo funcionaría un bucle?

Voy a crear el bucle dentro de una función, para no modificar ni crear estructuras temporales en el entorno global. 
La funcion se va a llamar `unir` y sirve solamente para est problema u otro exactamente igual. La idea de esto de ver cuan penoso es solucionar este problema con bucles y cuanto más vale la pena invertir tiempo en aprender a usar joins que escribir un bucle que haga lo mismo.

**No soluciona el problema de las fechas**, para eso abría que abrir otro `for` y otro `if`. Ya es suficientemente complicado como está.

No dudo que haya una mejor manera de hacerlo con bucles, pero de todos modos no tiene caso mejorarlo, los bucles son una solución suboptima desde cualquier punto de vista.

```
unir <- function (df1, df2){
  out <- data.frame()
  for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {   
      for (j in 1:ncol(df2)) {      
       if (df1[i,1] == colnames(df2)[j]) {
         x <- as.vector(df1[i,])
         y <- as.vector(df2[ ,j])          #Porque si no sale un data.frame
            for (k in 1:length(y)){        #Itero dentro del vector
              z <- rbind(cbind(x, y[k]))   #Armo la estructura de datos
              names(z)[ncol(z)] <- "dato_que_interesa_unir"   #Porque en cada ciclo hereda un nombre diferente
        }
       }
      }
  out <- rbind(out, z)                      #Uno recursivamente el resultado de cada ciclo del segundo for
  }
  return(out)
}

unir (df1, df2)

# Resultado

> unir(df1, df2)
    COD      LON     LAT ALT dato_que_interesa_unir
1  C037 -289.976 432.165 162              -9999.000
2  C037 -289.976 432.165 162                  1.456
3  C037 -289.976 432.165 162              -9999.000
4  C037 -289.976 432.165 162              -9999.000
5  C037 -289.976 432.165 162              -9999.000
6  C037 -289.976 432.165 162                  1.456
7  C037 -289.976 432.165 162              -9999.000
8  C037 -289.976 432.165 162              -9999.000
9  C038 -228.623 428.395 596              -9999.000
10 C038 -228.623 428.395 596              -9999.000
11 C038 -228.623 428.395 596              -9999.000
12 C038 -228.623 428.395 596              -9999.000
```

## Conclusión

`merge` y `join` sí, bucles `no`.

Comment: Me genera algo así como fichero de salida.....                          
 X.COD. X.LON. X.LAT. X.ALT. X.y.k..
1    COD    LON    LAT    ALT    y[k]
2    COD    LON    LAT    ALT    y[k]
3    COD    LON    LAT    ALT    y[k]

Answer (score 0):

En general, en **R** se suele tratar de evitar el uso de los  ciclos explícitos, es decir el `for` o el `while`, para ciertas operaciones. Esto, por que en muchos casos, resulta mucho más performante, sencillo  y claro, trabajar directamente con la funcionalidad base del lenguaje que ya está preparada para  las manipulaciones que deberemos que hacer.

En primer lugar vamos a importar los datos de tu ejemplo. Achiqué un poco la muestra para que todos los `data.frame` sean consistentes entre sí y para que el ejemplo quede más claro:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="COD LON LAT ALT
C037    -289.976   432.165   162
E000    -274.107   430.783   218
C068    -228.623   428.395   596", header= T, stringsAsFactors=F)

# Achicamos la muestra para que sea consistente con los códigos en df1
df2 <- read.table(text="C037 E000 C068
-1999  -9999   -9991 
1.456  -9998   -9992
-2999  -9997   -9993
-3999  -9996   -9994", header= T, stringsAsFactors=F)

# Dejamos solo 4 valores de fecha para que sea consistente con las 4 filas de df2
df3 <- read.table(text="Date
01/01/2000
02/01/2000
03/01/2000
04/01/2000", header= T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

La solución

```
# Agregamos la columna de fecha. Aquí se asume que el orden de df2 es el
# mismo que tiene df3.
df2$Fecha <- df3$Date 

# Modificamos el formato de df2 "ancho" a "largo"
df4 <- reshape(df2, 
               varying = list(names(df2[1:ncol(df2)-1])), 
               direction = "long", 
               v.names="VALOR")

#Renombramos valores de columnas y nos quedamos con las que nos interesan
df4$COD=colnames(df2)[df4$time]
df4 <- df4[, c(1, 5, 3)]

# Hacemos un merge final de los dos dataframe
df_final <- merge(df1, df4, by="COD", all=T)

df_final
```

Explicación:

Básicamente lo que hacemos es hacer consistente la estructura de `df2` a la estructura de `df1`, es decir, dónde cada fila será un `COD` y una `Fecha`, si vemos como nos queda `df4` luego del [`reshape()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html) y el resto de las normalizaciones antes del [`merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) resultará mas claro:

```
         Fecha  COD     VALOR
1.1 01/01/2000 C037 -1999.000
2.1 02/01/2000 C037     1.456
3.1 03/01/2000 C037 -2999.000
4.1 04/01/2000 C037 -3999.000
1.2 01/01/2000 E000 -9999.000
2.2 02/01/2000 E000 -9998.000
3.2 03/01/2000 E000 -9997.000
4.2 04/01/2000 E000 -9996.000
1.3 01/01/2000 C068 -9991.000
2.3 02/01/2000 C068 -9992.000
3.3 03/01/2000 C068 -9993.000
4.3 04/01/2000 C068 -9994.000
```

Como se vé, convertimos todo lo que era columna en fila, y ahora es bien sencillo, aplicar un [`merge()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) para "combinar" `df1` y `df4`, la salida final:

```
    COD      LON     LAT ALT      Fecha     VALOR
1  C037 -289.976 432.165 162 01/01/2000 -1999.000
2  C037 -289.976 432.165 162 02/01/2000     1.456
3  C037 -289.976 432.165 162 03/01/2000 -2999.000
4  C037 -289.976 432.165 162 04/01/2000 -3999.000
5  C068 -228.623 428.395 596 01/01/2000 -9991.000
6  C068 -228.623 428.395 596 02/01/2000 -9992.000
7  C068 -228.623 428.395 596 03/01/2000 -9993.000
8  C068 -228.623 428.395 596 04/01/2000 -9994.000
9  E000 -274.107 430.783 218 01/01/2000 -9999.000
10 E000 -274.107 430.783 218 02/01/2000 -9998.000
11 E000 -274.107 430.783 218 03/01/2000 -9997.000
12 E000 -274.107 430.783 218 04/01/2000 -9996.000
```